# How to use i18n with a Grails radioGroup?

Tags: grails, radio-button, gsp

How does the message needs to be set in messages.properties to get the label translated? (I'm on Grails 2.4.4)

Domain:

```
int handledBy
```

messages.properties:

````
Case.handledBy.1=Handled by A
Case.handledBy.2=Handled by B```
````

View:

```
<g:radioGroup name="handledBy" values="[1,2]">
    <tr class="prop">
        <td valign="top" class="name">
           <label><g:message code="${it.label}" />:</label>
        </td>
        <td valign="top" class="value ${hasErrors(bean:CaseInstance,field:'handledBy','errors')}">                               
            ${it.radio}
        </td>
   </tr>
</g:radioGroup>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `labels` attribute of the [g:radioGroup](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/ref/Tags/radioGroup.html) tag for this, like

```
<g:radioGroup name="handledBy" values="[1, 2]" labels="['Case.handledBy.1', 'Case.handledBy.2']">
    ...
    <label><g:message code="${it.label}"/>:</label>
    ...
</g:radioGroup>
```

and add messages in messages.properties

```
Case.handledBy.1=Handled by A
Case.handledBy.2=Handled by B
```